# One to Many Bidirectional mapping for already persisted data in Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Im trying to update my parent class with already persisted children objects.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

  public void addChild(Child child){
     this.children.add(child);
     child.setParent(this);
  }
}

@Entity
public class Child {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

  public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}

...

Seeder logic
@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;
@Autowired
private ChildRepository childRepository;

Child c1 = new Child();
childRepository.save(cr1);

Parent p1 = new Parent();
p1.addChild(c1)
parentRepository.save(p1);
```

This code segment runs but it never updates the parent_id in child table, and it always shown as Null.
When I add cascade all to the parent class it gives me `detached entity passed error` as the child already exists. Removing cascade all and adding CascadeType.MERGE makes the code run, however still the foreign key in the child is empty.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Therefore how do I handle this situation? In my scenario, the child will be present in the DB before the parent.

Answer (score 0):

when using CascadeType.ALL  : @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

You just need to do that for save opereation :

```
@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;

Child c1 = new Child();
Parent p1 = new Parent();
p1.addChild(c1)
parentRepository.save(p1);
```

and it will be ok.